# geom_bar from ggplot to plot character variables of df length

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `DF`

```
a   b
A   1
B   1
C   1
B   1
B   1
A   1
```

I am trying to produce bar plot with `ggplot` with `DF$a` on x axis and `DF$b` on y axis. I use the following

```
p <- ggplot(DF, aes(a,b)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

But it appears that `ggplot` plots only unique letters from `DF$a` while i want to plot all of those. How can i do it? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a new variable called order, which is unique in each row and plot with that instead. Then you could relabel the x-axis to match the original variable.

```
df$order <- as.factor(1:nrow(df))

ggplot(df, aes(x = order, y = b)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = df$order, labels = df$a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid defining a new variable as shown by @mhairi-mcneill by just pulling the rownames off as your x-value

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x = rownames(DF),y = b)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = DF$a)
```

Comment: interesting - this works fine on my machine. you may need to try wrapping `rownames(DF)` with `as.factor()`...

Comment: Yes, exactly, that was my mistake, thank you for help! :)